# Pictures not saving in media folder

Tags: python, html, django

I noticed that when I upload a profile picture the picture is not being saved in my media directory.

I have manually created the folder and referenced it in settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
```

document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
...
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='media')
```

forms.py

```
#basic form
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email')

# edit mentor profile
class MentorProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mentor
        fields = ('photo',)
```

and views.py:

```
def edit_user(request):
    user = request.user
    # form = MentorProfileForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        mentorform = MentorProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid() and mentorform.is_valid():
            form.save()
            mentorform.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s' % (reverse('teachers:edit_user')))
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        mentorform = MentorProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', {'form': form,
                                                                              'mentor_form': mentorform})
```

**EDIT**

As requested here is the html template I am using to upload the picture and other profile info. I am convinced that the problem is with my html. I'm not sure what else I could be doing wrong

```
<form id="edit-mentor-profile" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="photo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Avatar</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="media v-middle">
                            <div class="media-left">
                              <div class="icon-block width-100 bg-grey-100">
                                  <img id="image" style="width:99%;height:99%;">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <input type="file" id="files" class="btn btn-white btn-sm paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated/>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-control-material">
                                {{ form.first_name }}
                                <label for="edit-mentor-profile-first_name"></label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-control-material">
                                {{ form.last_name }}
                                <label for="edit-mentor-profile-last_name"></label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-control-material">
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                              {{ form.email }}
                              <label for="edit-mentor-profile-email"></label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-6">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                            <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" checked="">
                            <label for="checkbox3">Subscribe to our Newsletter</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group margin-none">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated>Save Changes</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Upon a first glimpse at your code, the image should be in `media/media/`. The `upload_to` specifies a path inside your media root.

Comment: @schwobaseggl thanks, have tried this, the photo still isn't being saved to the folder when i try upload it

Comment: Can you show your template

Comment: @VaibhavMishra I have added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

As @schwobaseggl said, file should be stored in `/media/media` folder. But there is another problem in your code, here:

```
mentorform = MentorProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)  # <-- Here
```

Here it should be:

```
mentorform = MentorProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user.mentor)
```

Because `MentorProfileForm` is using `Mentor` model, not `User` model. Also you need to fix the code for handling `GET` request:

```
def edit_user(request):
    user = request.user
    # form = MentorProfileForm(instance=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        mentorform = MentorProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user.mentor)
        if form.is_valid() and mentorform.is_valid():
            form.save()
            mentorform.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s' % (reverse('teachers:edit_user')))
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        form = UserForm(instance=user)  # <-- Here
        mentorform = MentorProfileForm(instance=user.mentor) # <-- Here
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', {'form': form,
```

Comment: Thanks, file still isn't saving when after i upload it

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code in your html template. Where you are using form tag.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 ---------        --------
 ---------Your code-------

 </form>
```

Comment: I added my template to the question, I already had this in my form tag

Comment: Where are using MentorProfileForm in template.

Comment: yeah, just noticed that, mind showing me how. I still want to show a preview of the picture about to be uploaded though